# Hashbang, pjax, or djax for dynamic pages in WordPress?

Tags: google, wordpress, search-engines, jquery

I am modifying a current WP theme that uses child pages loaded into tabs via jQuery and hashtags. For example, `http://example.com/category` would be the parent page with tabs. Clicking on one of those tabs loads the child page, which WordPress knows as `http://example.com/category/tab1`, into the div dynamically, and changes the URL to `http://example.com/category/#tab1`.

What I'm trying to do is make the pages crawlable by Google, so that our tabs show up in search results as individual pages.

Google's own documentation seems to recommend using the "hashbang" method (https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started), and then serving up HTML snapshots of each tab.

But other developers I've read strongly recommend not using this method, and instead using pjax to dynamically load the content while making the URLs appear to be separate pages, so the SE will crawl it anyway. further research showed that djax is a slimmed down version of pjax, written specifically for WordPress.

I'm a little out of my depth here in trying to figure out which path I should go down, and how to convert the theme I'm working on to one of these methods. So, my question is:

Should I go with Google's recommendation of the hashbang method, or pjax, or djax? Why?

Whichever one I should start developing with, can anyone provide me with a way to get started learning how to use it and implement it? Most of the documentation I've found is way out of my depth.

Answer (score 1):

All three of the methods work for what you are trying to do. The question is which are you willing to use? OR which is easier for you to do?

As for my personal preference, I prefer Hashbang. For me, is the easiest to pick up and use and understand the documentation and implementation into working code.

Comment: Hashbang seems to me like the easiest to understand, at least...but why would others say that it's "breaking the web one link at a time"? Is there legitimate concern about longevity, especially since Google says this is a temporary fix?

Comment: Good question. There is always people that dislikes something regardless of how good or bad it is. I don't see any issues with it for the future as of yet.